# Export deftype methods

Tags: javascript, clojure, google-closure-compiler, clojurescript

I am trying to create object in javascript and call a method. Method name is munged. I tried to use externs.js without luck.

```
(deftype ^:export SceneMain []
  Object
  (handleShow [_]
    (display-categories)))

;; should be used in javascript as:

var s = new SceneMain();
s.handleShow();

;; Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'handleShow'
;; Uncaught TypeError: Object #<dg> has no method 'handleShow'
```

Here is my externs.js

```
var SceneMain = {};
SceneMain.handleShow = function() {};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use exportSymbol:

```
(goog/exportSymbol "SceneMain" SceneMain)
(goog/exportSymbol "SceneMain.prototype.handleShow" SceneMain.prototype.handleShow)
```

It works even with advanced optimizations:

```
ca("SceneMain",mg);
ca("SceneMain.prototype.handleShow",SceneMain.prototype.Cb);
```

Answer (score 4):

No entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish there.

`externs.js` is useful when you're using an external javascript library from Clojurescript not compiled with Google's Closure compiler, main reason for that is when optimization beyond whitespace is used, the compiler is not mangling the external library.

Take for instance [MixPanel Javascript](https://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/javascript) api.

Say you have the following cljs code using that api:

```
(defn track 
   ([name data]
      (.track js/mixpanel name 
             (clj->js data)))
   ([name]
      (.track js/mixpanel name)))
```

You'll need to define in your `externs.js`

```
 var mixpanel = {};
 mixpanel.track = function() {};
```

To avoid Closure compiler mangling invocations to that object/function.

Now, if you want to call a Clojurescript function from Javascript, using `^:export` will do.

Say you have:

```
(ns test.cljs)

(defn ^:export testfn
   []
   (.log js/console "test"))
```

From javascript you do:

```
 test.cljs.testfn()
```

Comment: I want to get closure-compiler to not mangle handleShow function name, there is an example of javascript usage. It seems it's a known issue - http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-698